# How to backup the realm database data to google drive?

Tags: android, realm

I am new to the realm database.I am facing the issue in backup the realm database data into the google drive.I read the documentation but i don't know how to implement the function step by step.also i tried the code

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        realm.getDefaultInstance();

        GlucosioApplication glucosioApplication = (GlucosioApplication) getApplicationContext();
        realm = glucosioApplication.getDBHandler().getRealmIstance();

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.title_activity_backup_drive));

        backup = glucosioApplication.getBackup();
        backup.init(this);
        connectClient();
        mGoogleApiClient = backup.getClient();

        backupButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.activity_backup_drive_button_backup);
        restoreButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.activity_backup_drive_button_restore);
        backupButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openFolderPicker();
            }
        });

        restoreButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openFilePicker();

            }
        });
    }


    private void openFilePicker() {
        //        build an intent that we'll use to start the open file activity
        IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi
                .newOpenFileActivityBuilder()
//                these mimetypes enable these folders/files types to be selected
                .setMimeType(new String[]{DriveFolder.MIME_TYPE, "text/plain"})
                .build(mGoogleApiClient);
        try {
            startIntentSenderForResult(
                    intentSender, REQUEST_CODE_SELECT, null, 0, 0, 0);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to send intent", e);
            showErrorDialog();
        }
    }

    private void openFolderPicker() {
        try {
            if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                if (intentPicker == null)
                    intentPicker = buildIntent();
                //Start the picker to choose a folder
                startIntentSenderForResult(
                        intentPicker, REQUEST_CODE_PICKER, null, 0, 0, 0);
            }
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to send intent", e);
            showErrorDialog();
        }
    }

    private IntentSender buildIntent() {
        return Drive.DriveApi
                .newOpenFileActivityBuilder()
                .setMimeType(new String[]{DriveFolder.MIME_TYPE})
                .build(mGoogleApiClient);
    }

    private void downloadFromDrive(DriveFile file) {
        file.open(mGoogleApiClient, DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY, null)
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(DriveApi.DriveContentsResult result) {
                        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                            showErrorDialog();
                            return;
                        }

                        // DriveContents object contains pointers
                        // to the actual byte stream
                        DriveContents contents = result.getDriveContents();
                        InputStream input = contents.getInputStream();

                        try {
                            File file = new File(realm.getPath());
                            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
                            try {
                                try {
                                    byte[] buffer = new byte[4 * 1024]; // or other buffer size
                                    int read;

                                    while ((read = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                                        output.write(buffer, 0, read);
                                    }
                                    output.flush();
                                } finally {
                                    output.close();
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } finally {
                            try {
                                input.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Restart drive message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        // Reboot app
                        Intent mStartActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        int mPendingIntentId = 123456;
                        PendingIntent mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), mPendingIntentId, mStartActivity, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
                        AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                        mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 100, mPendingIntent);
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                });
    }

    private void uploadToDrive(DriveId mFolderDriveId) {
        if (mFolderDriveId != null) {
            //Create the file on GDrive
            final DriveFolder folder = mFolderDriveId.asDriveFolder();
            Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(mGoogleApiClient)
                    .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(DriveApi.DriveContentsResult result) {
                            if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Error while trying to create new file contents");
                                showErrorDialog();
                                return;
                            }
                            final DriveContents driveContents = result.getDriveContents();

                            // Perform I/O off the UI thread.
                            new Thread() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    // write content to DriveContents
                                    OutputStream outputStream = driveContents.getOutputStream();

                                    FileInputStream inputStream = null;
                                    try {
                                        inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(realm.getPath()));
                                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                        showErrorDialog();
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                                    int bytesRead;
                                    try {
                                        if (inputStream != null) {
                                            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buf)) > 0) {
                                                outputStream.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        showErrorDialog();
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }


                                    MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                                            .setTitle("glucosio.realm")
                                            .setMimeType("text/plain")
                                            .build();

                                    // create a file in selected folder
                                    folder.createFile(mGoogleApiClient, changeSet, driveContents)
                                            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveFolder.DriveFileResult>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onResult(DriveFolder.DriveFileResult result) {
                                                    if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                                                        Log.d(TAG, "Error while trying to create the file");
                                                        showErrorDialog();
                                                        finish();
                                                        return;
                                                    }
                                                    showSuccessDialog();
                                                    finish();
                                                }
                                            });
                                }
                            }.start();
                        }
                    });
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    backup.start();
                }
                break;
            // REQUEST_CODE_PICKER
            case 2:
                intentPicker = null;

                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    //Get the folder drive id
                    DriveId mFolderDriveId = data.getParcelableExtra(
                            OpenFileActivityBuilder.EXTRA_RESPONSE_DRIVE_ID);

                    uploadToDrive(mFolderDriveId);
                }
                break;

            // REQUEST_CODE_SELECT
            case 3:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    // get the selected item's ID
                    DriveId driveId = data.getParcelableExtra(
                            OpenFileActivityBuilder.EXTRA_RESPONSE_DRIVE_ID);

                    DriveFile file = driveId.asDriveFile();
                    downloadFromDrive(file);

                } else {
                    showErrorDialog();
                }
                finish();
                break;

        }
    }

    private void showSuccessDialog() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void showErrorDialog() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    public void connectClient() {
        backup.start();
    }

    public void disconnectClient() {
        backup.stop();
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        finish();
        return true;
    }
```

The above code i don't know it works or not.Also the error is occurring in GlucosioApplication glucosioApplication = (GlucosioApplication) getApplicationContext(); what library should i import for GlucosioApplication.Please help me how to back up the data to google drive.

Comment: `realm.writeCopyTo(path)`

Comment: realm.writeCopyTo(path)  by using this method how can i back up data

Comment: by backing up the file you create with `realm.writeCopyTo(path)`

Comment: My doubt is to how to make back up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get realm file:

```
  Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(Application.config);
    realm.close();
    File f = new File(realm.getPath());
```

To save that file use Google drive API to save file

```
private void saveFiletoDrive(final File file, final GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient) {
    // Start by creating a new contents, and setting a callback.
    Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(DriveApi.DriveContentsResult result) {
                    // If the operation was not successful, we cannot do
                    // anything
                    // and must
                    // fail.
                    if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                        Log.e("ERROR", "Failed to create new contents.");
                        return;
                    }
                    Log.e("SUCCESSFULL", "Connection successful, creating new contents...");
                    // Otherwise, we can write our data to the new contents.
                    // Get an output stream for the contents.
                    OutputStream outputStream = result.getDriveContents()
                            .getOutputStream();
                    FileInputStream fis;
                    try {
                        fis = new FileInputStream(file.getPath());
                        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                        int n;
                        while (-1 != (n = fis.read(buf)))
                            baos.write(buf, 0, n);
                        byte[] photoBytes = baos.toByteArray();
                        outputStream.write(photoBytes);

                        outputStream.close();
                        outputStream = null;
                        fis.close();
                        fis = null;

                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        Log.v("EXCEPTION", "FileNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage());
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        Log.v("EXCEPTION", "Unable to write file contents." + e1.getMessage());
                    }

                    String title = file.getName();
                    MetadataChangeSet metadataChangeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                            .setTitle(title).build();

                 /*   if (mime.equals("application/vnd.google-apps.photo")) {*/
                    Log.v("CREATING", "Creating new file on Drive (" + title
                            + ")");
                    Drive.DriveApi.getFolder(mGoogleApiClient,
                            Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(mGoogleApiClient).getDriveId()).createFile(mGoogleApiClient,
                            metadataChangeSet,
                            result.getDriveContents());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Backing up of Google Drive...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Back up Successfull!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
}
```

Google Api client

```
 GoogleApiClient client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
```

Comment: I am using realm.getDefaultInstance(); instead of  Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(OpexApplication.config);

Comment: Realm Configuration from Application class

Comment: Null pointer exception occurs in  File f = new File(realm.getPath());

Comment: Get realm instance from application class

Comment: This exception is occurring  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: GoogleApiClient is not configured to use the API required for this call.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145169/discussion-between-prabha-karan-and-hammad-akram).